# How can I make a Custom made SMS permission Dialog

Tags: android, permissions, sms

I use the follow code to get SMS permission from user. But I wish to add some description when shows the permission Dialog. How I can do it? Or is the way to do it? thanks.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to SEND_SMS - requesting it");
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};

            requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't. If you want to show a rationale, you need to create your own way to do so, before requesting the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can create an `AlertDialog` and add the description there. Here is an example how to achieve that

```
try {
    new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setMessage("Your description about the permission")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            })
            .create()
            .show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception in case context is not present / destroyed, etc
}
```

Alternatively, you can let user to send SMS without any permission at all. Create these helper methods inside your `Activity`

```
private boolean sendSms(final String phoneNumber, final String content) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    if (isIntentAvailable(intent)) {
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", content);
        startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isIntentAvailable(final Intent intent) {
    return getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
            .size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: I test your first code but shows two dialog. Is the way to show my description in one dialog? thanks.

Comment: Yes, it will shows 2 dialogs, because it is supposed to show a pre-dialog before showing the real dialog for requesting permissions. Since the dialog for requesting permissions is handled by android framework, you can't modify it, so you can't show your description in 1 dialog.